# How to handle a hierarchy of properties in ASP.NET 5 AppSettings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET 4 to organize settings, I am prefixing the setting key with a small word that indicates where this config is used (e.g. key="dms:url", "sms:fromNumber" .... etc).

In ASP.NET 5, the AppSettings configuration is mapped to a strongly typed class.
what is the property that i need to build for "dms:url"? How could map dashes & special chars to a C# property in ASP.NET 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can organize your configuration file within a hierarchy in the config.json

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "SiteTitle": "PresentationDemo.Web",
    "Dms": {
      "Url": "http://google.com",
      "MaxRetries": "5"
    },
    "Sms": {
      "FromNumber": "5551234567",
      "APIKey": "fhjkhededeudoiewueoi"
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "MyConnectionStringHere. Included to show you can use the same config file to process both strongly typed and directly referenced values"
    }
  }
}
```

We defined the AppSettings as a POCO class.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public AppSettings()
    {
        Dms = new Dms(); // need to instantiate (Configuration only sets properties not create the object)
        Sms = new Sms(); // same
    }

    public string SiteTitle { get; set; }
    public Dms Dms { get; set; }
    public Sms Sms { get; set; }
}

public class Dms
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int MaxRetries { get; set; }
}

public class Sms
{
    public string FromNumber { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

We then load the configuration into an instance of `IConfigurationSourceRoot` and then set values of AppSettings using GetSubKey.  The best practice would be to do this in ConfigureServices and add it to the DI Container.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var configuration = new Configuration()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Application settings to the services container.
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSubKey("AppSettings"));

        //Notice we can also reference elements directly from Configuration using : notation
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
    }
}
```

We can now provide access in a controller through the constructor.  I set the setting values explicitly the constructor but you could use the entire IOptions

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private string _title;
    private string _fromNumber;
    private int _maxRetries;

    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        _title = settings.Options.SiteTitle;
        _fromNumber = settings.Options.Sms.FromNumber;
        _maxRetries = settings.Options.Dms.MaxRetries;
    }
```

If you wanted to keep everything flat and use a pseudo hierarchy like you have been doing, you can, but ":" isn't a valid symbol for a variable name.  You would need to use a valid symbol like "_" or "-" instead.

Comment: Hi @gerald-davis, Looks like I need to reconfigure something in Startup.cs
Can you please guide me?
I mean:
var appSettingsConfig = services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSubKey("AppSettings"));
will not be enough!! Right?!

I got Object Reference Exception because Dms property in AppSettings is null.

I created Dms class then a property called Dms in AppSettings class.

Comment: Using the config file above there is no Dms property of AppSetting.  Using the config file above it would be AppSettings.Options.Dms.FromNumber as an example.  Note the "Options" in the property chain.  I am responding from my phone.  When I get to a workstation I will update the answer w/ initialization code from startup.cs (unless someone else does).

Comment: thank you for replying, waiting your answer .. because i cannot find a helpful blog post explaining that .. Maybe if you know some resource please send it to me.

Comment: Provided an update which shows entire process from config file to referenced setting properties.  Using the default ASP.NET 5 Web template in VS 2015 and making modifications where the code above differs you should be able to get a working example.

Comment: IConfiguration does not seem to have a method for GetSubKey(string) anymore (since release).